# Consultar os 3 últimos dias em que houve registro na tabela

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tenho uma tabela chamada `OperacoesCaixa` e nela tenho os seguintes campos:

```
Cod, Valor, DataOp
```

Bom preciso fazer um `select` que me retorne os lançamentos dos 3 últimos dias, porém não quero ter que informar uma data.

Supondo que tenho um lançamento realizado 15 dias a trás o `select` tem que retornar os 3 último dias.

Eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OperacoesCaixa
WHERE
    DataOp BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY
    DataOp
DESC
```

O problema e que ele pega a data atual, se não houver nenhum lançamento nos últimos 3 dias o `select` não vai me retornar nada.

-------- edit --------

Bom para facilitar vou posta um exemplo real.

Vamos usar a data de 17-07-2020 como referência do dia da consulta.

Exemplo 1:

Tenho os seguintes dados na tabela:

```
Cod Valor       DataOp

1   85.20       13-07-2020
2   97.14       13-07-2020
3   89          13-07-2020
4   100         15-07-2020
5   247.85      15-07-2020
6   58          16-07-2020
7   97          16-07-2020
8   86          16-07-2020
9   875         17-07-2020
10  85.20       17-07-2020
```

Bom o `select` deve retornar o seguinte resultado:

```
10  85.20       17-07-2020
9   875         17-07-2020
8   86          16-07-2020
7   97          16-07-2020
6   58          16-07-2020
5   247.85      15-07-2020
4   100         15-07-2020
```

Ou seja, os lançamento dos 3 últimos dias.

Exemplo 2 notem que nos 3 últimos dias não houve lançamentos:

Tenho os seguintes dados na tabela:

```
Cod Valor       DataOp

1   85.20       5-07-2020
2   97.14       5-07-2020
3   89          5-07-2020
4   100         8-07-2020
5   247.85      8-07-2020
6   58          9-07-2020
7   97          9-07-2020
8   86          10-07-2020
9   875         10-07-2020
10  85.20       10-07-2020
```

A resposta deve ser:

```
10  85.20       10-07-2020
9   875         10-07-2020
9   875         10-07-2020
8   86          10-07-2020
7   97          9-07-2020
6   58          9-07-2020
5   247.85      8-07-2020
4   100         8-07-2020
```

Resumindo independente da data de hoje quero que seja listado todos os registros dos 3 dias que houve registro.

Comment: Sua explicação está confusa. Se quer pegar os 3 lançamentos anteriores independente da data em que ocorreram então selecione os lançamentos anteriores à data atual, ordene em ordem decrescente de DataOp e utilize um LIMIT 3.

Comment: Não seriam as três datas mais recentes ?

Comment: @Motta editei minha pergunta colocando um exemplo para ficar mais claro

Comment: Faça um select distinct das datas , ordene decrescente e com "limit" pegue as N maiores , faça agora um select da tabela original buscando por IN o select acima como subselect , só tenho dúvida neste limit ou top pois não yso mysql

Comment: @Motta poderia postar uma resposta com um exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Se são os últimos 3 dias, seria mais fácil dizer "data maior que data atual - 3", o que em um comando SQL seria:

`WHERE DataOp > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY`

Pronto, vou deixar a query anterior, porque pode interessar a alguém.

Agora vamos ao caso da pergunta. Como precisa listar os valores todos, pegando as últimas datas, precisa de uma subquery. Se fossem totais, bastava agrupar por data, order e pegar as últimas 3, assim:

```
select DataOp, SUM(Valor) from OperacoesCaixa
group by DataOp
order by DataOp DESC
limit 3;
```

Como precisa listar tudo, podemos usar essa mesma query para selecionar as datas, removendo o `SUM` é claro e colocar na query principal:

```
select * from OperacoesCaixa
where DataOp in (select * from (
                 select DataOp from OperacoesCaixa
                  group by DataOp
                  order by DataOp DESC
                  limit 3) as sub)
order by DataOp desc;
```

Note que, eu adicionei um segundo nível na subquery, isso porque a subquery direta dá erro ao usar o `LIMIT`, que aqui é essencial para pegar as 3 datas apenas.

Veja aqui funcionando: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2X55LZBmqcFh7WHnaKMAfo/1

Comment: Não é bem isso, editei minha pergunta colocando um exemplo para ficar mais claro

Comment: entendi, a partir da data atual, vc quer q encontre os 3 ultimos dias antes que tenha registros, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo, agora você entendeu.

Comment: Tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: sim tenho, é que não tive tempo de fazer um exemplo :)
basicamente precisar agrupar por data e ordenar, dai pegar as as 3 ultimas datas

Comment: pronto, da uma olhada na resposta, qualquer dúvida avisa

Answer (score 0):

Creio ser algo assim , posso ter errado em algum detalhe da síntaxe

```
--1
SELECT
    distinct DataOp
FROM
    OperacoesCaixa
order by DataOp desc    
    
--2 
select DataOp
from
(
SELECT
    distinct DataOp
FROM
    OperacoesCaixa
order by DataOp desc
) virtual limit 3

--3
select *
from 
where DataOp in
(select DataOp
from
(
SELECT
    distinct DataOp
FROM
    OperacoesCaixa
order by DataOp desc
) virtual limit 3
) virtual2
```